# Why is the PHP localeconv() returning an empty array on Windows 7?

Tags: php, windows, locale, intl

So, localeconv() seems to be ignoring the locale in my php script, and returns a basically empty array.

I've found numerous questions, etc. the answers to which all boiled down to the locale not being set correctly for Windows.

I believe this script is setting it using a valid value, and I can confirm the current locale is the one I want to use, but regardless of what the current locale is, localeconv() just returns the same (mostly) empty array.

What I'm looking to see is the mon_decimal_point and mon_thousands_separator values being populated with something.

So, my question is:

### What do I have to do to get real results from localeconv()?

#### Sample script:

```
<?php
echo locale_get_default()."\n";
echo setlocale(LC_MONETARY, locale_get_default()) . "\n";
echo setlocale(LC_MONETARY, '0')."\n";

$locale_info = localeconv();
print_r($locale_info);

echo setlocale(LC_MONETARY, null) ."\n";
echo setlocale(LC_MONETARY, '0')."\n";

$locale_info = localeconv();
print_r($locale_info);
```

#### Script output:

```
sve
Swedish_Sweden.1252
Swedish_Sweden.1252
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [thousands_sep] =>
    [int_curr_symbol] =>
    [currency_symbol] =>
    [mon_decimal_point] =>
    [mon_thousands_sep] =>
    [positive_sign] =>
    [negative_sign] =>
    [int_frac_digits] => 127
    [frac_digits] => 127
    [p_cs_precedes] => 127
    [p_sep_by_space] => 127
    [n_cs_precedes] => 127
    [n_sep_by_space] => 127
    [p_sign_posn] => 127
    [n_sign_posn] => 127
    [grouping] => Array
        (
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
        )

)
English_United States.1252
English_United States.1252
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [thousands_sep] =>
    [int_curr_symbol] =>
    [currency_symbol] =>
    [mon_decimal_point] =>
    [mon_thousands_sep] =>
    [positive_sign] =>
    [negative_sign] =>
    [int_frac_digits] => 127
    [frac_digits] => 127
    [p_cs_precedes] => 127
    [p_sep_by_space] => 127
    [n_cs_precedes] => 127
    [n_sep_by_space] => 127
    [p_sign_posn] => 127
    [n_sign_posn] => 127
    [grouping] => Array
        (
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
        )

)
```